# Building a calculator that will always display to the power of 6 or 9

Tags: javascript, math

I have a calculation based on a counter that gives me a large number, I convert that to an exponential. I then split that to show the number x 10 ^ exponential. The issue is the user always wants the number displayed to the ^6 if less than 1 billion and to the ^9 if over a billion. I need to figure out a way to move the decimal of the result based on the exponential difference.

For example if the result of 
26 x 1000 x 10^4 is displayed as 2.6 x 10^8 I need to display it as 260 x 10^6.
If 9 x 10 x 10^4 is displayed as 9 x 10^5 I need to display as .9 x 10^6

Code below:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("AddOne");

var count = 0;

function Count() {
  //count and beep

  count += 1;
  //AddOne.innerHTML = count;
  YCount.innerHTML = count;
  //document.getElementById("myAudio").load(); 
  //document.getElementById("myAudio").play(); 
}

function Calculate() {
  var calc
  var y = document.getElementById("YCount").innerHTML;
  var dilution = document.getElementById("Dilution").value;
  if (dilution) {
    calc = y * dilution * Math.pow(10, 4);
  } else {
    calc = y * Math.pow(10, 4);
  }

  //getting exponential and only 2 digits after decimal
  //var expon = calc.toExponential(2);
  var expon = calc.toExponential();

  var fValue = expon.substring(0, expon.indexOf("e+"));
  var sup = expon.substring(expon.indexOf("e") + 2);
  //var test = fValue.toFixed(2);
  var floor = 6 * Math.floor(sup / 6);
  var dec = 1 + (sup % 6);

  //take the decimal value -subtract 1 and move left by that number



  var result = document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Result: " + calc + "<br />Exponential: " + calc.toExponential() + "<br /> Power: " + fValue + " x 10<sup>" + sup + "</sup><br />Floor: " + floor + "<br />Decimal shift: " + dec;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Calculation: <br />Number<br />
    <span class="tab">= total </span><br />
    <span class="tab">x dilution factor (if any) x (1 x 10<sup>4</sup>) </span></p>
  <br />
  <button id="AddOne" onclick="Count()" type="button" class="button">Count</button>

  <br /><br />
  <label id="YCount"> </label> X <input type="text" id="Dilution" placeholder="dilution factor" /> X 10<sup>4</sup>

  <button class="button" id="Answer" type="button" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
  <br /<br />
  <br /><label id="Result">Result: </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly code your requirements as follows:

```
var sup = 9;
if(calc < 1e+9)
    sup = 6;
var fValue = calc / Math.pow(10, sup);
```

Here is the complete modified snippet.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("AddOne");

var count = 0;

function Count() {
  //count and beep

  count += 1;
  //AddOne.innerHTML = count;
  YCount.innerHTML = count;
  //document.getElementById("myAudio").load(); 
  //document.getElementById("myAudio").play(); 
}

function Calculate() {
  var calc
  var y = document.getElementById("YCount").innerHTML;
  var dilution = document.getElementById("Dilution").value;
  if (dilution) {
    calc = y * dilution * Math.pow(10, 4);
  } else {
    calc = y * Math.pow(10, 4);
  }

  //getting exponential and only 2 digits after decimal
  //var expon = calc.toExponential(2);
  var expon = calc.toExponential();

  var sup = 9;
  if(calc < 1e+9)
      sup = 6;
  var fValue = calc / Math.pow(10, sup);

  var floor = 6 * Math.floor(sup / 6);
  var dec = 1 + (sup % 6);

  //take the decimal value -subtract 1 and move left by that number



  var result = document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Result: " + calc + "<br />Exponential: " + calc.toExponential() + "<br /> Power: " + fValue + " x 10<sup>" + sup + "</sup><br />Floor: " + floor + "<br />Decimal shift: " + dec;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Calculation: <br />Number<br />
    <span class="tab">= total </span><br />
    <span class="tab">x dilution factor (if any) x (1 x 10<sup>4</sup>) </span></p>
  <br />
  <button id="AddOne" onclick="Count()" type="button" class="button">Count</button>

  <br /><br />
  <label id="YCount"> </label> X <input type="text" id="Dilution" placeholder="dilution factor" /> X 10<sup>4</sup>

  <button class="button" id="Answer" type="button" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
  <br /<br />
  <br /><label id="Result">Result: </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I played with your code and came up with a way to do this. There are four steps on each calculation.

1. you need to check whether the result was greater than 1 billion.
2. Create a multiplier variable with the value of 6 if result is less, or 9 if is greater than 1 billion.
3. Create another variable representing the leading number, and divide it by 10 ^ the multiplied (6 or 9).
4. concatenate the result from step 3 with the string "x ^ 10" concatenated with the result from step two.

Here's the code, which can be added to your Calculator function:

```js
var over1Bil = calc > 1000000000
var exp6or9 = over1Bil ? 9 : 6
var multiplier = 10 ** exp6or9
var exp6or9res = calc / multiplier

var result = document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = (
  "Result: " 
  + calc 
  + "<br />Exponential: " 
  + calc.toExponential() 
  + "<br /> Power: " 
  + fValue 
  + " x 10<sup>" 
  + sup 
  + "</sup><br />Floor: " 
  + floor 
  + "<br />Decimal shift: " 
  + dec
  + "<br /> 6 || 9 exp: "
  + exp6or9res
  + " x 10^"
  + exp6or9
)
```